# Get time of usage of other apps (iOS)

Tags: ios, time

Is it possible to somehow get the time of usage of other installed apps and do some action? (Eg. If some time of usage is achieved.)
iOS

Comment: Nope. I don't think so.

Comment: Yeah, no. You don't get to even see what other apps are installed.